# Count two different text items in a row or column

Tags: worksheet-function, countif

I have a table (schedule) that I have a COUNT set up to count the number of times a text occurs.

My table:

```
  A  |   B   |    C    |  D  |   E   |   F   |    G    |  H 
John | Rooms | RoomsPM | OFF | Rooms | Rooms | Laundry | OFF
```

My formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:H1, "ROOMS")
```

the result is 3.

In this example, I have it set to count the # of times "Rooms" is in row. But I would also like to include the # of times "RoomsPM" is in row. 
What formula can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, [sumproduct](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) works for this -

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:H1="Rooms")+(B1:H1="RoomsPM"))
```

With this, it's basically a

```
countif(array, condition)OR(array,condition).
```

If you change the `+` to a `*` it will replace the `OR` with `AND`.

You can also use this type of thing, but sumproduct is a better solution

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(B1:H1,"Rooms"),COUNTIF(B1:H1,"RoomsPM"))
```